# Converting String to Integer in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to convert a String to an Integer using the EditText field in Android, but my application crashes Whenever try to click the button. The String section work but the issue is only when the user types an integer in the EditText Field named Number.

```
 package com.example.addingvalu;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        EditText Number,txtval;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               }


        public void ViewaNumber(View V1)
        {
            txtval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stringvalue);
            Number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numbers_text);
            //String ab;
            int ed;
            ed = Integer.parseInt(Number.getText().toString());     

            if(txtval.length() != 0)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "String " + txtval.getText().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(Number.length() !=0)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the IDE isn't mistaking 'Number' for the class java.lang.Number?

Comment: Could you please post the Logcat too.

Comment: Yes..As @TimKranen pointed out rename `Number` to something like `Number1`..give a try..

Answer (score 0):

It is a very good practice not to start methods and attributes with UpperCase. 
Also add a try/catch to print the possible error out and have some clues on how to fix it.
Try:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        EditText number,txtval;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               }


        public void ViewaNumber(View V1)
        {
            txtval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stringvalue);
            number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numbers_text);
            //String ab;
            int ed;
            ed = 0;
            try{
                ed = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());     
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(txtval.length() != 0)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "String " + txtval.getText().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(number.length() !=0)
            {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look.

```
  try{
        int ed=Integer.valueOf(number.getText().toString());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope it will help you...!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this, there are main two issues.

- You're calling `parseInt()` on an empty string if there was no number
  entered.
- You're passing an `int` primitive to `Toast.makeText()`

You could just append the `int` primitive to a `String` and that would be valid:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Number " + ed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The above is the equivalent to:

```
"Number " + new Integer(ed).toString()
```

You could also just convert back to `String` for the Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(ed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is working and tested code that fixes both issues:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText number,txtval;
    int ed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ViewaNumber(View V1)
    {
        txtval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stringvalue);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Numbers_text);
        //String ab;



        if(txtval.length() != 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "String " + txtval.getText().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(number.length() !=0)
        {
            //Make sure number is non-empty before calling parseInt()
            ed = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Number " + ed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```